# Making dynamic background colors in loop

Tags: vue.js

I have an iteration through `color_attributes` **:**

```
  <div v-for="colorAttribute of selectedProduct.color_attributes" :key="selectedProduct.id">
      <span class="color-attribute" style="background: #{{colorAttribute}}"></span>
  </div>
```

How I can change the `span` background-color dynamically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to bind the color property value dynamically.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedProduct: {
        color_attributes: ['green', 'blue', 'yellow']
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(colorAttribute, index) of selectedProduct.color_attributes" :key="index">
      <span class="color-attribute" :style="`background: ${colorAttribute}`"> {{ colorAttribute }} </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could bind the style to the object :

```html
<div v-for="colorAttribute of selectedProduct.color_attributes" :key="selectedProduct.id">
    <span class="color-attribute" :style="{background: '#'+colorAttribute}"></span>
 </div>
```

or with string template:

```html
<span class="color-attribute" :style="`background: #${colorAttribute}`">
```